# Make a button that opens a fresh new tab in HTML, no link, just a new tab

Tags: html, button

Is it possible to make a button, that when clicked, opens a new tab. Not any link, just a new tab. so far I have `<button target="_blank" onclick="location.href = ''">New Tab</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Simply link to `about:blank` with the target `_blank`

```html
<a target="_target" href="about:blank"><button>New Tab</button></a>
```

Comment: for me, this just opens a new tab that is completely white. it might be because I use Opera GX browser though.

Comment: @Wh1sperDevelops that's because it's a completely blank, empty tab. You cannot navigate to the users default home page, this is as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, its impossible. You can't navigate to the users default home page, as stated by Gradyn Wursten. Though you can navigate to a blank white page, using about:blank